# MS Access VBA using the IN operator

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am creating a query and have the following SQL line

```
WHERE (((TblBreaksGiven.FinancialYear)='" & sql_FinancialYear & "') 
AND 
((TblBreaksGiven.Quarter) IN (" & sql_Quarters & "))); "
```

sql_quarters is based on a list box on a form, if I select one or more quarters the query works, however, if no quarter is selected I want the default to be all quarters. I don't want to hard code set sql_quarters to something like 'Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4' and have that used if the count of items in the list box is 0. Is there almost like a wildcard I can use with IN I tried something basic like IN (*) to no avail.

Comment: Change the SQL not to include if selected count is 0, use `if .... then ....else`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That is an option but I want to avoid that as I will have several of these list box parameters and it will get difficult to continually change the SQl.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
WHERE ((((TblBreaksGiven.FinancialYear)='" & sql_FinancialYear & "') AND 
(((TblBreaksGiven.Quarter) IN (" & sql_Quarters & "))) 
OR (TblBreaksGiven.Quarter) LIKE '*" & sql_Quarters & "*' )); "
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `*` rather than `%` in Access SQL?  You could also lose all the brackets except the single ones in the `IN` statement and also lose the table name if `FinancialYear` and `Quarter` only appear in one table within the query. `WHERE FinancialYear='" & sql_FinancialYear & "' AND Quarter IN (" & sql_Quarters & ") OR Quarter LIKE '*" & sql_Quarters & "*'"`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I think so too. I don't think this would work as well.

Comment: I have updated the query. The OR condition is nested with the Quarter only and it should work if 'sql_Quarters' returns empty string. The query should be check actually, @Naz - Can you please check it?

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that bit - remove all brackets except the `IN` statement and to enclose the two parts of the `OR` statement

Comment: As we don't have the database, only @Naz can verify this solution and i am waiting to hear from him!

Comment: @Naz - Would you please let us know what is working and what is not ?

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir I tried it but it didn't work, I get a syntax error. if I choose Q1, Q2 I get IN ('Q1,Q2') or like (*Q1,Q2'). If I choose nothing I get IN ('*') or like (****')

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir Thank you for your help but I have gone a different route.

Comment: As i can't check it, i can't fix the tiny things. What i gave you is an idea and i still believe it will work if you can implement it properly in your form. Best of luck.